# KeyValuePair from WCF - conversion error when consuming via ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF web service which is returning a KeyValuePair. ie:

```
List<KeyVauePair<string,int>>
```

When I test this in the WCF Test Client it says the type returned is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String,System.Int32>>
```

So thats good and dandy. I then go to consume this web method in ASP.Net via:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> testkv = WCF.GetOptionSetValues("contact", "types");
```

But this does not work and the compiler says:

**Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[] to System.Collections.Generic.List System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair**

For some reason it seems the compiler thinks the return type from the web method is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[]
```

But its not an array.  Its a:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
```

I am wondering why the compiler is interpreting the web method as KeyValuePair[] instead of KeyValuePair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Collection of `KeyValuePair` and a List of `KeyValuePair` are not the same thing.  If you want a List, you probably need to iterate through your collection and build one.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in WCF.GetOptionSetValues("contact", "types"))
{
    myList.Add(pair);
}
```